# DFS for graphs - finding a path between start and end nodes

Tags: depth-first-search

I need to adjust this DFS algorithm to find a path between '0' and '3' and not to traverse the whole graph. Could someone help?

```
def dfs(visited_vertices, graph, current_vertex):
    # Check if current_vertex hasn't been visited yet
    if current_vertex not in visited_vertices:
        print(current_vertex)
        # Add current_vertex to visited_vertices
        visited_vertices.add(current_vertex)
        for adjacent_vertex in graph[current_vertex]:
            # Call recursively with the appropriate values
            dfs(visited_vertices, graph, adjacent_vertex)

dfs(set(), graph, '0')

graph = {
  '0' : ['1','2'],
  '1' : ['0', '2', '3'],
  '2' : ['0', '1', '4'],
  '3' : ['1', '4'],
  '4' : ['2', '3']
}
```

[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqjnA.png)

I tried:

```
dfs(visited_vertices, graph, current_vertex, end_vertex):

    if current_node == end_node:
        break;
```

```
dfs(set(), graph, '0', '3')
```

but I don't know where to put these lines of code

Answer (score 0):

`break` makes no sense when used outside of a loop: it is intended to break out of a loop. If you want to exit a function, you should use `return`.

As you probably want to get the *path* as returned value, make sure to return a list. You can then test whether a recursive call returns a path, and if so, extend it as you get out of recursion.

What you need:

- The extra parameter. The initial call and the recursive call should pass the `end_vertex` as argument
- The first statement could indeed check for a match. If there is a match, then return a path (list) with just that node (one entry)
- Capture the result from the recursive call. If it is not `None`, then we have found a match at a deeper level, and can just prefix the current node to the returned path, and return that extended path.

```py
def dfs(visited_vertices, graph, current_vertex, end_vertex):
    if current_vertex == end_vertex:
        return [end_vertex]  # Return a path 
    if current_vertex not in visited_vertices:
        visited_vertices.add(current_vertex)
        for adjacent_vertex in graph[current_vertex]:
            # Capture the result of the recursive call
            path = dfs(visited_vertices, graph, adjacent_vertex, end_vertex)
            if path:  
                # We have a match: return a path that has the current node added to it
                return [current_vertex, *path]

graph = {
  '0' : ['1','2'],
  '1' : ['0', '2', '3'],
  '2' : ['0', '1', '4'],
  '3' : ['1', '4'],
  '4' : ['2', '3']
}

# Get the result (path) from DFS
path = dfs(set(), graph, '0', '3')
print(path)
```

Note that DFS does not necessarily return the *shortest* path -- just *a* path. If you need the shortest path, then it is common to use BFS instead of DFS.